# How are videos in 23.97 frames per second shown

Tags: display, video

How does the Mac deal with video content played back at a rate that does not neatly fit into 60 fps screen refresh?

I have never noticed 23.97 content looking wrong to my eyes, so is this a solved issue?

Comment: I am thinking it might be handled in an overlay (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_overlay), though that article does not seem to go into detail about frame rates.

Answer (score 1):

24fps videos on a 30fps display (closer to 23.976fps on 29.97fps) divides out into 4/5. Conversion of film frame rate to display/TV frame rate is known as [Telecine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecine). NTSC video uses [2:3 Pulldown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-two_pull_down) as the method for displaying 24fps on a 30fps device. 2 of the 5 frames in each pulldown cycle are interlaced.

You can do the same math with 23.976fps/24fps on a 59.94fps/60fps display: 23.976/59.94 = 2/5. While I don't know the exact pulldown method for this frame rate, the concept is essentially the same.

While each individual frame is available as a still, your mac handles the pulldown and frame interlacing on the fly.

(This is why 120fps and 144fps displays are great - 24fps divides into 120fps and 144fps evenly, so the video shows each video frame for 5 and 6 display frames, respectively. No interlacing artifacts.)

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced—even if you convert on-the-fly to 29.97, you would then need to stretch the video and audio ever so little to make this work.

And I am in a PAL region, where 25 FPS is even more common, which does not convert nicely to 60 FPS.